# Unable to get Yup Validation to work in MUI with React Hook Form in a masked Controller field

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

I am on a dead end here with React Hook Form phone masking and validation. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

I am using React Hook Form and Yup for form and validation and MUI for UI. I was somehow able to add masking to my phone field using react-hook-form Controller component and react-input-mask for masking. But now I am not getting the Yup validation errors (helper text) that we get on form submit, on blur or on change.

I think it's because the masking already has hyphens which the field takes as value so it's technically never empty. But the problem is that when I add this field to the form, I don't get helper text to any of the other fields as well.

I have created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-hooks-8zsgbb) for it. I want to make it a required field with minimum and maximum 15 characters (including + sign and two hyphens). I am not getting any helper text or error message and the form submits even if the user typed just one character.

Here's the Yup validation schema:

```
const Schema = Yup.object().shape({
  cellPhone: Yup.string().min(15).max(15).required('Cell phone is required'),
});

const methods = useForm({
  resolver: yupResolver(Schema),
  defaultValues,
});
```

Here's the RHF form field:

```
<Controller
  name="cellPhone"
  control={control}
  defaultValue=""
  render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
    <InputMask
      mask="+99-999-9999999"
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
    >
      {(inputProps) => (
        <TextField
          error={!!error}
          helperText={error?.message}
          label="Cell phone"
          variant="outlined"
          type="text"
          fullWidth
          required
          {...inputProps}
        />
      )}
    </InputMask>
  )}
/>
```

Here's the codesandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-hooks-8zsgbb

If you have any solution, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve it? I use rules: field to setup validation instead of YUP, and the same, it doesn't work. Field mask works, but field itself always valid. @umar-munir

Answer (score 0):

As one of the possible solutions is to change validation mode on whole form. Form validation errors shown only on submit by default, time to time i do forget about it and spend time again and again. It's ok to show error messages only on form submit but it feels like validation works anyway (at least validation functions run, but no errors shown, that's quiet strange)

To change validation mode use:

```html
useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    ...
  },
  mode: 'all',
})
```